# how to use forecast function for simple moving average model in r?

Tags: r, forecasting, predict, moving-average

I want to predict the future values for my simple moving average model. I used the following procedure:

```
x <- c(14,10,11,7,10,9,11,19,7,10,21,9,8,16,21,14,6,7)   
df <- data.frame(x)    
dftimeseries <- ts(df)  
library(TTR)      
smadf <- SMA(dftimeseries, 4) # lag is 4    
library(forecast)    
forecasteddf <- forecast(smadf, 4) # future 4 values
```

When run the above code, my forecast values are the same for all the next 4 days. Am I coding it correctly? Or, am I conceptually wrong?

The same is the case with exponential moving average, weighted moving average, and ARIMA also.

Comment: Just to take a rolling average you can look at the package `zoo` and in particular `rollmean()`. For arima you can fit your model using `Arima()` from `forecast` and then make your forcasts using `forecast.Arima`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a moving average model you can read [here](https://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/ORMM/omie/operation/unit/forecast/moving_avg.html)

*"Since the model assumes a constant underlying mean, the forecast for any number of periods in the future is the same...".*

So, your result are to be expected considering the characteristics of the moving average mode.

Comment: sir then what about my arima model?

Comment: Your ARIMA model is a moving average model, so the rule applies to your case

Answer (score 0):

The forecast is from the fpp2 package and the moving average function is from the smooth package.

This is an example:

library(smooth)
library(fpp2)
library(readxl)
setwd("C:\Users\lferreira\Desktop\FORECASTING")

data<- read_xlsx("BASE_TESTE.xlsx") 
 ts <- ts(data$`1740`,start=c(2014,1),frequency=4)

> fc <- forecast(sma(ts),h=3)
>   Error: The provided model is not Simple Moving Average!